# Why isn't -ss option of ffmpeg work accurate when providing exact keyframe

Tags: ffmpeg, codec

I am using copy stream codec and I need not have `negative PTS` values in output.
This is how the command looks

`ffmpeg -y -ss 00:44.002292 -to 01:04.022292 -i "https://drive.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=1tEt19OyfM0BH43WcoECwQnGzu8eallRC" -c copy -avoid_negative_ts 1 11.mp4 -hide_banner` .

values for `-ss` and `-to` are keyframe timestamps. But the output video starts at a timestamp previous(at `pkt_pts_time=38.997292`) to what i specify. So i decided to specify next keyframe value for `-ss` option but soon i realized that it works accurately on other videos.
ffmpeg version: 4.1.1

Why this happens? What is specific about this video?

**Edit**
Seek time is subtracting in my case by `3*AV_TIME_BASE / 23` value
 (ffmpeg_opt.c:1179)

Comment: This must be the saddest video of all time. Just from quick observation, once you go to 44.1, you get a more correct (?) starting point. Could be rounding. Run ffmpeg with `-debug_ts` to see what happens.

Comment: @slhck yes it works for 44.1, `-debug_ts` prints `pkt_dts:1715200 pkt_dts_time:38.8934 off:-44002292`, i enabled debug logging and noticed this: `Setting codecpar->delay to 2 for stream st: 1` and i found out that it is seeking based on DTS and the final seek_timestamp is subtracting by `3*AV_TIME_BASE / 23` this value (ffmpeg_opt.c:1179) and i'm not an expert so i don't get it